# Prove $f(x) \in C^\infty$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}\right)$ if $\|x\|<1$ and $f(x)=0$ if $\|x\|\geq1$
How can I prove that $f$ is from $C^\infty$ class?

**My work**

If $\|x\|<1$ then $f'(x)=\dfrac{-2\|x\|}{(1-\|x\|)^2}\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}\right)$ which is clearly continous and derivable.

**Is this enough?**

the hint of the books says to use this theorem
[image]

which says:
*Let be $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ continous, derivable in $\langle a,b \rangle$ , except for a point $c$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=L$, prove that $f'(c) $ exists and is equal to $L$* But i can't figure out how does it work in the problem

Comment: About your work: I'm missing where $\nabla f$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to provide some hints. Let's break $\mathbb{R}^n$ into three parts: $||x||<1$, $||x||=1$, and $||x||>1$. It should be clear that $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $||x||>1$.

For $||x||<1$, you can find $f'$. Note $$f'(x) = g_1(||x||) \cdot \exp \Big (\frac{-1}{1-||x||^2} \Big)$$ where $g_1(||x||)$ is a differentiable (continuous) rational function of $||x||$ on $||x||<1$. By induction we claim $$f^{(n)}(x) = g_n(||x||) \cdot \exp \Big (\frac{-1}{1-||x||^2} \Big)$$ with $g_n$ differentiable and rational on $||x||<1$. If you prove this, then we'll have that $f$ has continous derivatives of all orders (a product of continuous functions is continuous) on $||x||<1$, and hence $f$ is $C^\infty$ here.

For $||x||=1$ this is where the hint comes into play. Try to show (again inductively) $f^{(n)}$ is continous here and $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ for all $n$ and such $x$.

Comment: *Did he* find $f'$? $f$ is a function of several variables, not just one.

Comment: your indicationes clear my mind, thank you. My $f'$ is bad, I will recalculate it